# Xunit test SerializableError return object value

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit

I am writing unit tests of controller logic with Xunit.

One of my controller actions returns a `BadRequestObjectResult` with the `ModelStateDictionary` object:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

To do this my test case adds a ModelState error like this:

```
controller.ModelState.AddModelError("Test", "This is a test model error");
```

In the Assert statements of my test case I am checking the return object which is type `SerializableError`:

```
var returnError = Assert.IsType<SerializableError>(objectResult.Value);
Assert.Single(returnError);
Assert.True(returnError.ContainsKey("Test"));
Assert.True(returnError.ContainsValue("This is a test model error"));
```

The `Assert.Single(returnError);` and `Assert.True(returnError.ContainsKey("Test"));` checks pass successfully as expected.

However, the check on the check of the error value fails (it returns `false` but I expect it to return `true`):

```
Assert.True(returnError.ContainsValue("This is a test model error"));
```

I can see from debugging that the Value seems to be nested in an extra `string` object:

[image]

But I have been unable to write a test which tests the value.  How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in another answer, value of Dictionary is an array, so you should address that in the assertions.

```
var returnError = Assert.IsType<SerializableError>(objectResult.Value);

var errors = objectResult.Value as SerializableError;
Assert.Single(errors);
Assert.True(errors.ContainsKey("Test"));

var errorValues = returnError["Test"] as string[];
Assert.Single(errorValues);
Assert.True(errorValues.Single() == "This is a test model error");
```

Because `SerializableError` inherits from Dictionary, you should be able to do it in clearer way with help of FluentAssertions library

```
var expected = new SerializableError
{
    { "Test", new[] {"This is a test model error"}},
};

objectResult.Value.Should().BeOfType<SerializableError>();
objectResult.Value.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```

Comment: On `Assert.Single(actualError);` I get a "cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable" error

Comment: I'm sorry I'm having a bad day with this.  On `Assert.True(actualError.Single() == "This is a test model error");` I get a " 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Single' and no accessible extension method 'Single' accepting a first argument of type 'object' "

Comment: I've used the FluentAssertions library and that approach works.  Thank you for the tip. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your value is a list. so Value[0]  or Value.First(). It' a keyvaluepair so you should be able to access it by returnError[keyName].

Comment: I've not been able to find a way to access the value by index

Comment: Thanks.  I can access it like this `var values = returnError["Test"] as String[];
            Assert.True(values[0] == "This is a test model error");` but there must be a better way?

Comment: You can use item[key] -> (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelstatedictionary?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the response to ObjectResult see below

var result = response.Result as BadRequestObjectResult

or

var result = response.Result as OkObjectResult

now you can access the value using result.Value property